# Robust standard errors for cross-sectional data: what is a "large" sample size?

Tags: t-distribution, robust-standard-error

I know that others have asked about robust standard errors ([Robust standard errors in econometrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43787/robust-standard-errors-in-econometrics) and [Always Report Robust (White) Standard Errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452/always-report-robust-white-standard-errors)).  An [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/5626/30765) to the latter question made this reference to Wooldridge (2009):

> The robust standard errors and robust *t* statistics are justified only as the sample size becomes large.  With small sample sizes, the robust *t* statistics can have distributions that are not very close to the *t* distribution, and that can throw off our inference.

I have a cross-sectional dataset, and if the null hypothesis of the test for heteroskedasticity is rejected, what criteria should I use to determine if my sample size is "large enough" for a *t* distribution?  I know that there have been a few posts that mention that the $n>30$ rule of thumb is flawed.

Note: I was unable to ask this question in the comments of the answer since I have not reacheda 50 reputation yet.  My apologies in advance that this question is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a long comment, but I don't think such thresholds exist since they seem fairly dependent on the type of heteroskedasticity.

Moreover, there are several finite-sample adjustments that you can make to speed up convergence, such as multiplying the squared residuals by n/(n-k), which some software already does by default. Some of these adjustments are more involved than others.

Angrist and Pischke's [book](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/) recommends using $\max \{het. robust,conventional\}$ errors (p. 307). This ROT seems to perform well in their simulation. Others recommend reporting both and letting the reader decide. [Imbens and Kolesar (2012)](http://econ.ucsb.edu/~doug/245a/Papers/Robust%20Standard%20Errors%20Small%20Sample.pdf) offer a readable survey of this literature (including several simulations), though theirs is a more complicated solution.